# Python: Convert a pandas Series into an array and keep the index

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, k-means

I'm running a k-means algorithm (k=5) to cluster my Data. To check the stability of my algorithm, I first run the algorithm once on my whole dataset and afterwards I run the algorithm multiple times on 2/3 of my dataset (using a different random states for the splits). I use the results to predict the cluster of the remaining 1/3 of my data. Finally I want to compare the predicted cluster with the cluster I get when I run k-means on the whole dataset. This is where I get stuck.

Since k-means always assigns different labels to the (more or less) same clusters I can't just compare them. I tried using `.value_counts()` to reassign the labels 0 to 4 based on their frequency. But because I run this check multiple times, I need something that works in a loop.
Basically when I use `.value_counts()` I get something like this:

```
     PredictedCluster  
4              55555  
0              44444
2              33333
1              22222
3              11111
```

I wish I could turn this into an array, where the labels are sorted by size:

```
a = [[4, 55555],[0,44444],...,[3,11111]]
```

Can anyone please tell me how to do this or what other approaches could I use to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the one-liner below could work:

```
a = list(map(list, df["PredictedCluster"].value_counts().items()))
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use:

```
(df['PredictedCluster'].value_counts(ascending=False)
                       .reset_index()
                       .to_numpy())
```

This will count the values, sort (descending) by those counts, then convert the results to a `numpy.ndarray`.

If you'd like the results in a list, simply append `.tolist()` to the end of the statement.